# Can't access my Flask application through a VPN

Tags: python, flask, vpn, anyconnect

I work for a large institution where I have a RedHat server. Once I am connected to the VPN I can access and develop on the server from my home through SSH. I run the following simple flask app:

**The flask_app.py on WORK_SERVER**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

### ROUTES ###
# Home page
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return("this is a home page")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**Here's the (expected) output from starting the flask app in the terminal:**

```
[my_terminal]$ python flask_app.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'flask_app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://my.ip.add.ress:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

However, when I attempt to access any of those IP Addresses I can't connect with my VPN-connected local machine. Is there issues with port-forwarding? I figure it's more of a VPN problem than a Flask problem...

Tried to connect to server's Flask application through VPN-connected browser and couldn't. Also tried a curl command (e.g. curl http://my.ip.add.ress:5000) which also failed.

Comment: While you did not specify what _exactly_ "can't connect" means, I am almost certain this has nothing to do with Flask and is purely a networking issue. But you can easily test that by running dummy HTTP server with [`python -m http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). If you can't reach that one either, you'll know it is not a Flask issue.

Comment: That's what I figured. Also... the last two sentences specify what 'can't connect' means ;)